How to make new table with two different tables and matching information
I'd like to make a new table with two different data table, like these.
Table 1) Name to Code: matching data from pair-wise comparison
#Table1
Name   Code
 A      B
 A      C
 A      D
 A      E
 B      C
 B      D
    ...

Table 2) Information of each Name: includes information like genes, proteins (string characters)
# Table2
Name   info
 A      grade 1
 B      grade 2
 C      grade 3
 D      grade 4
 E      grade 5
    ...

with these tables,
I'd like to make the next one.
# Table3
Name    info    Code    info
 A     grade 1   B     grade 2
 A     grade 1   C     grade 3
 A     grade 1   D     grade 4
    ...

Adding info to each Name or Code after matching.
I guess that it can work by replacement of column "Name" with "info", with keeping the pairwise relationship.
In R environment,
how can I make above table?
Many thanks,
merge(Table1, Table2, by = "Name") %>%
 select(Name, Code, Info)

This makes a table containing only Name, Info, and Code...

mutate(df1, across(everything(), ~deframe(df2)[.],.names = "{col}_info"))

  Name Code Name_info Code_info
1    A    B   grade 1   grade 2
2    A    C   grade 1   grade 3
3    A    D   grade 1   grade 4
4    A    E   grade 1   grade 5
5    B    C   grade 2   grade 3
6    B    D   grade 2   grade 4


df1 %>%
   rowid_to_column() %>%
   pivot_longer(-rowid) %>%
   left_join(df2, join_by(value == Name)) %>%
   pivot_wider(values_from = c(value, info), names_vary = 'slowest') %>%
   select(-rowid)

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  value_Name info_Name value_Code info_Code
  <chr>      <chr>     <chr>      <chr>    
1 A          grade 1   B          grade 2  
2 A          grade 1   C          grade 3  
3 A          grade 1   D          grade 4  
4 A          grade 1   E          grade 5  
5 B          grade 2   C          grade 3  
6 B          grade 2   D          grade 4  


Base R:
nms <- with(df2, setNames(info, Name))
cbind(df1, sapply(df1, \(x)nms[x]), row.names = NULL)

  Name Code    Name    Code
1    A    B grade 1 grade 2
2    A    C grade 1 grade 3
3    A    D grade 1 grade 4
4    A    E grade 1 grade 5
5    B    C grade 2 grade 3
6    B    D grade 2 grade 4


cbind(rowid = seq(nrow(df1)),stack(df1))|>
   merge(df2, by.x = 'values', by.y = 'Name')|>
   reshape(direction = 'wide', v.names = c('values', 'info'),
           timevar = 'ind', idvar = 'rowid')|>
   subset(select = -rowid)

  values.Name info.Name values.Code info.Code
1           A   grade 1           B   grade 2
2           A   grade 1           C   grade 3
3           A   grade 1           D   grade 4
4           A   grade 1           E   grade 5
5           B   grade 2           C   grade 3
6           B   grade 2           D   grade 4

